# Cancel accidental Siri activation

Tags: ios, siri

**How do I tell Siri to go away when I activate it by accident?**

The best I can come up with is "Cancel", which works but replies that "there's nothing to cancel". Functional, but irritating.

Searching on Google has thus far just turned up a whole lot of stuff about how to turn Siri off altogether, which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: Try "Goodbye" and Siri will reply "Bye!" Or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than pressing the home button or sleep button, you can say a list of words:

- Goodbye
- Bye
- See you
- So long
- See you soon/later

Answer (score 3):

You can press the home button again or say "Goodbye"

Answer (score 1):

"Thank you, that's all" also works